# setting external library /bin folder in cmake in windows

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, point-cloud-library, bin

My question is related to PCL installation and here it goes:

I compiled PCL using MSVC2013 and I updated manually my PCLConfig.cmake to point to all its dependences (3rdParty libs). The problem is that I want also to set its binaries /bin folders in the same cmake file (instead of adding /bin to environment variables). Is there a way to do that ?

What makes this question pertinent is that I'am testing different versions of PCL (1.6, 1.7, 1.8...), so won't adding the /bin folders to path of all these versions will create some kind of confict between them afterwards (in the retreive step) ?

*To be clear, what i succeded to do is that, using cmake, I can choose the PCLConfig of the PCL version I want, but when running my program (succefully compiled), it throws a missing pcl_****.dll missing, which is logic because the PCL/bin folder is not added to the system environement. so, my question is "can I add the PCL/bin floder to the project environment using the CMakeLists of my project? (instead of adding it to system environment)"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `The problem is that I want also to set its binaries /bin folders in the same cmake file` - Could you elaborate your problem more? Do you want to export `PATH` variable with `<local-install>/bin` directory included from the script `PCLConfig.cmake`? If so, just add `set(ENV{PATH} "$ENV{PATH};<local-install>/bin")` into `PCLConfig.cmake`. Such way, futher CMake commands like `find_program()` will search your `/bin` directory too.

Comment: I edited my question. in short, is there a way to set/edit a system environment variable using cmake ?

Comment: Script may set environment variables only for configuration stage. For make resulted executable to work, one need to properly adjust RPATH. There is nice description of [RPATH handling in CMAke](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary fix i found is generating my project with the specified PCL version wanted and then Adding the bin folders manually in MSVC 2013 :

Debugging->Environment << PATH=path_to_lib\lib;%PATH%

Tsyvarev, I'm looking for your proposition and I'll let you know if it worked. Looks like a cleaner way...
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

That PATH information for debugging is stored in the "user" project file.  I've written a CMake function to generate such a file automatically.  This worked for VC10.  I assume it'll still work, or it may need some modification.  The principal is to keep an empty user project file as a template, and CONFIGURE_FILE the contents to set whatever you want.  I've set mine up so that you first do: `SET(USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${directory}")` then call the macro `CREATE_USER_FILE` with the name of the CMake project.

CreateUserFile.cmake:

```
get_filename_component(MY_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} PATH)
SET(USERFILE_TEMPLATE ${MY_DIRECTORY}/msdev.vcxprojuser.template CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

MACRO(CREATE_USER_FILE _projectName)

# Find user and system name
SET(SYSTEM_NAME $ENV{USERDOMAIN} CACHE STRING SystemName)
SET(USER_NAME $ENV{USERNAME} CACHE STRING UserName)

IF (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 4)
    SET(USERFILE_ARCH Win32)
ELSE()
    SET(USERFILE_ARCH x64)
ENDIF()

SET(USER_FILE ${_projectName}.vcxproj.user)
SET(USERFILE_TEMPLATE ${USERFILE_TEMPLATE})

SET(OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${USER_FILE})
# Configure the template file
CONFIGURE_FILE(${USERFILE_TEMPLATE} ${USER_FILE} @ONLY)

ENDMACRO(CREATE_USER_FILE)
```

And here's the template file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|@USERFILE_ARCH@'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>@USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|@USERFILE_ARCH@'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>@USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|@USERFILE_ARCH@'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>@USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|@USERFILE_ARCH@'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>@USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

ProTip: do something similar to generate a .bat file to launch your program after setting the PATH that CMake computes, so you can run it from outside Visual Studio.